# How can I 'Like' pages / url with Facebook SDK API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this code:

```
$facebook->api('/me/likes/', 'post',  array('url' => 'http://www.google.com'));
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) App does not have permission to make this call thrown in
```

The scope (permissions) is:

```
'scope' => 'publish_stream, email'
```

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that can be programmatically liked is facebook Objects with the `likes` connection.

Taken from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ :

> You can comment on or like any object that has a /comments or /likes
>   connection by posting to https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/comments
>   and  https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes

---

**UPDATE :**

The `user` object also has a likes connection, but that is used for aggregation of likes for other objects, it is not possible to "like" a user. ( thankfully ;P )
Thanks to @Juicy Scripter for pointing this out...

Comment: With one exception, `user` object. ;) Which have this connection for other reason, aggregation of likes for other objects

Answer (score 0):

From: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

To get the list of page likes from a user you need to HTTP Get to `/me/likes` with a valid *user* access token with at least the `user_likes` permission.  There is **no** API method call to **add** a page to the likes or **remove** a page from the likes.